# Express JS not setting Base URL CSP Headers

Tags: javascript, express, server-side-rendering

My ExpressJs Server that is rendering my React Frontend is not setting my CSP Headers at all, but all other Relative URLS set the Headers just fine.

Here are some code snippets for reference.

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let app = express();
let sql = require('mssql');
let router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
let axios = require('axios')
const https = require("https");
require('dotenv').config()
const compression = require('compression');
const helmet = require('helmet')

let PORT = 80;
let buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'build');
console.log(__dirname)
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(buildPath));
app.use(router);
app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet())
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy())
app.disable("x-powered-by")

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set({
      'Content-Security-Policy':"default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src https://www.youtube.com/; object-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'https://www.youtube.com/'; connect-src 'self';",
      'Strict-Transport-Security':"max-age=31536000",
      'X-Content-Type-Options': "nosniff"
    });
    next();
  });

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("HIT * ROUTE")
    app.disable("x-powered-by")
    res.set({
        'Content-Security-Policy':"default-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-src https://www.youtube.com/; object-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'https://www.youtube.com/'; connect-src 'self';",
        'Strict-Transport-Security':"max-age=31536000",
        'X-Content-Type-Options': "nosniff"
    })
    .sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/build/index.html'));
  });
```

I have tried setting the headers for all route with app.use, it works perfect for all relative URLS. I also tried explicitly setting the Headers in the * route where the HTML file is served.

Comment: So are you getting the `HIT * ROUTE` log? My guess is the route is not hit, because your `router` already handles the request. Put your middlewares *above* the handler

Comment: Nope, I'm not even getting that log. Sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Place ALL your middleware that sets headers you want on every request to be BEFORE the `express.static()` routes.